# CSS overflow scroller crops background color

Tags: html, css, angular

I am creating a web and need to make a **scroller** appear. I tried using **overflow: auto**, but then other problem appeared. Here is a simple example of my problem. I have outer div with property **overflow: auto** and component in angular4 (or in other words another div) that has new background color. When scroller appears and I **scroll to right background color disappears**. How to have scroller and background color to stay?

```css
.outer {

    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    border: thin solid black;
    overflow: auto;
    background: red;
}
.inner{
background:Yellow;

}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>
 Scroll to right -> ********************************************
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the inner div to `display: inline-block;`, so that the width won't get limited by the container's width. Also add `min-width: 100%;` as needed.

```css
.outer {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border: thin solid black;
  overflow: auto;
  background: red;
}

.inner {
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inner p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>
      Scroll to right -> ********************************************
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

add this: `width: fit-content;`

```css
.outer {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border: thin solid black;
  overflow: auto;
  background: red;
}

.inner {
  background: Yellow;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>
      Scroll to right -> ********************************************
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```